# Cannot create bootable USB with Boot Camp, "there is not enough space available on the disk"

Tags: bootcamp, windows, install, mojave

I am trying to install Windows 10 on my MacBook (macOS Mojave 14.4.4). I have used Windows 10 till last week and I had to remove all the partitions with a complete refresh of macOS too.

Since then I have been trying to use the Boot Camp method to install Windows 10.  I'm getting this error all the time:

> Your bootable USB drive could not be created
>   There is not enough space available on the disk.

When I check Disk Utility the current HD has 196GB free.

I'm using the latest macOS update from Apple site.

How to resolve this?

System log:

```
2019-04-05 08:54:41 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Initializing configuration
2019-04-05 08:54:41 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Registered App nameID: Microsoft AutoUpdate_MSau04 | Copies: 1 | Installations: Location: /AppSupport Version: 4.9.19030902
2019-04-05 08:54:41 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> HelperTool Status: helperToolExists YES, helperToolCodesigned: YES
2019-04-05 08:54:41 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Attempted to register: MSau04, Preferences Available: YES, Re-Registration: YES, Success:NO
2019-04-05 08:54:41 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Microsoft Update Assistant launched
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Skip webservice. Only 23 since last call.
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Invalid action type (null)
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> MWSOnBoot handled action name Null
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> launched via LaunchAgent
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Changing timeNextUpdate from 2019-04-04 20:46:02 +0000 to 2019-04-05 07:54:42 +0000
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Scheduling timer to fire 0.000000 seconds from now.
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Update check timer fired at 2019-04-05 07:54:42 +0000
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Checking for updates
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Server is Reachable
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Checking for updates.
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Downloading Chks - Will Attempt to download chks for 1 registered apps
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Fetching file Success. File: https://officecdn-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/pr/C1297A47-86C4-4C1F-97FA-950631F94777/MacAutoupdate/0409MSau04-chk.xml
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Downloading Chks - Result: 1. Missing Manifests: 0. Downloaded chks: 1.
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Downloading chk files got 1 files. Will check if any indicates an update is available.
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Downloading chk files - Found 0 apps and 0 suites that should be checked for updates
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> No updates found.
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Changing lastUpdate from 2019-04-04 08:46:02 +0000 to 2019-04-05 07:54:42 +0000
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Starting timer (not forcing one day)
2019-04-05 08:54:42 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Scheduling timer to fire 43199.998382 seconds from now.
2019-04-05 08:55:12 [Microsoft Update Assistant] <Info> Microsoft AU Daemon terminated normally
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is not warning of insufficient space on your internal disk, but rather that of your external USB drive. Make sure there is sufficient space on your **external drive** and that it is of a sufficient size (at least 16 GB, possibly more depending on the Windows installer you are using).

<sup>The system log snippet provided is not relevant to Boot Camp but rather that of Microsoft AU, the updater for Microsoft Office.</sup>

Comment: I have tried that way too, still same error.  Where do I get system log specific to bootcamp? Thanks

Comment: ...the bootcamp goes on without any issues until Downloading windows support software, then it asks for password to make changes. Then it fails with that error.